# Adding multiple StyleConstants to an AttributeSet

Tags: java, addattribute, defaultstyleddocument

I have a string of text: "This is a |<good>| mountain to |<ski>| on."

I want *|<good>|* and *|<ski>|* to appear red, italic, FontSize 9.

I've set individual AttributeSets

```
  StyleContext myProtected = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
  AttributeSet attR = myProtected.addAttribute(myProtected.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.RED);
  AttributeSet attB = myProtected.addAttribute(myProtected.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Background, Color.BLUE);
  AttributeSet attI = myProtected.addAttribute(myProtected.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Italic, Boolean.TRUE);
  AttributeSet attS = myProtected.addAttribute(myProtected.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.FontSize, 9);
```

and I have a regex that finds the patterns correctly. But if i try to set multiple AttributeSets to the same match, only the first one respects the regex. The others just apply themselves to the whole string. Here's the whole class:

```
class ElementHighlight2 extends DefaultStyledDocument {
  //private final  MutableAttributeSet XRED = new SimpleAttributeSet();

  StyleContext myProtected = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
  AttributeSet attR = myProtected.addAttribute(myProtected.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.RED);
  //AttributeSet attB = myProtected.addAttribute(myProtected.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Background, Color.BLUE);
  AttributeSet attI = myProtected.addAttribute(myProtected.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Italic, Boolean.TRUE);
  AttributeSet attS = myProtected.addAttribute(myProtected.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.FontSize, 9);    

@Override
  public void insertString (int offset, String Pstr, AttributeSet RedBlue) throws BadLocationException
  {
   super.insertString(offset, Pstr, RedBlue);
   String text = getText(0, getLength());
   int pre = pipeCharEnd(text, offset);
   if (pre < 0) pre = 0;
   int post = pipeCharStart(text, offset + Pstr.length());
   int prewords = pre;
   int postwords = pre;

   while (postwords <= post) {
                if (postwords == post || String.valueOf(text.charAt(postwords)).matches("\\|")) {
                    if (text.substring(prewords, postwords).matches("(\\|\\<[^\\>]*\\>)"))
                        setCharacterAttributes(prewords, postwords - prewords +1, attR, false);
                        setCharacterAttributes(prewords, postwords - prewords +1, attI, false);
                        setCharacterAttributes(prewords, postwords - prewords +1, attS, false);

                    prewords = postwords;
                }
                postwords++;
            }
  }
```

If somebody could help me learn the best practice that I have not yet discovered to achieve this, I will be most grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating individual attributes and combining them with `setCharacterAttributes`, I think you could create a combined attribute set:

```
AttributeSet attR = myProtected.addAttribute(myProtected.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.RED);
AttributeSet attI = myProtected.addAttribute(attR, StyleConstants.Italic, Boolean.TRUE);
AttributeSet attS = myProtected.addAttribute(attI, StyleConstants.FontSize, 9);
```

and then apply only the combined `attS`.